# 404 Error in @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created a Spring MVC project with STS. In this project I have the default HomeController with @RequestMapping("/"). This controller is called correctly.

Then I have additionally this controller

```
package de.gl.rm;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import de.gl.rm.model.Project;

@Controller
public class Projects {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Project> getProjects() {
        Project p1 = new Project(1, "P1");
        Project p2 = new Project(2, "P2");

        ArrayList<Project> list =  new ArrayList<Project>();
        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        return list;
    }
}
```

But on /projects my webapp doesn't response. My config is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js" />
<resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css" />
<resources mapping="/img/**" location="/resources/img" />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="de.gl.rm" />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.gl.rm.controller" />
```

I don't know why /projects don't work. Has anybody an idea?

Thanks

Comment: how u caling /projects usong ajax?

Comment: No, browser request from adress bar.

Comment: then remove `ResponseBody` annotation and you should return view name from Get method.

Comment: And of I always want to retrieve json

Comment: then call through AJAX and render data in your view.

Comment: `<mvc:annotation-driven>` ?

Comment: What is full URL of this call?

Comment: localhost:8080/rm/projects

Comment: Whats the error log on your 404 - can you include the stacktrace in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a part of the answer:

1- Remove `<context:component-scan base-package="de.gl.rm.controller" />` because `<context:component-scan base-package="de.gl.rm" />` will scan `de.gl.rm` and the sub packages as well.

2- Remove

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

because you have a @ResponseBody (usually to handle some AJAX requests inside a web page) so it's just the `List<Project>` printed when you request  `localhost:8080/rm/projects` no need of a view resolver, but you need a content negociation, if you want JSON add `produces = {"application/json"}` and add the lib to do the job in your pom, jackson for example.

3- Your web.xml need to be configured with a servlet dispatcher :

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rm/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

With `rm` for the `url-pattern` since your url is `localhost:8080/rm/projects` (assuming that your context path is `/`) otherwise it would be `localhost:8080/<context-path>/rm/projects`

4- I suggest you to use only the annotations for the configuration (without any xml and a web.xml empty)

Comment: I wouldn;t suggest removing the view resolver, it is probabyl used elsewhere

Comment: Yes sure, it's just if we use only the @ResponseBody, it was just for the understanding, but you right, it's certainly used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the logged output, there are a number of problems, but none of them should result in a 404...

You are returning a reposnsebody, so it will return a list of Projects, as either json or xml. However as it is a custom class you will need to provider a converter/serializer.

Add mvc-annotation driven to your config, that will give you the default serializers/converters (which might work with the toString method of your project class straight away, but not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your servlet xml.

This solved the 404 problem for me when I was trying to use BindingResults in my controller to check if the results of a form where valid in relation to my data model (e.g: don't accept a null name for a person).

Hope this solve your problem :)